# Updating visitor count if a random number is equal to a fixed one [if random == fixed: increase visitor count]

Tags: php, random, statistics

When working on one of Sweden's most popular websites, I came across a (to me) strange snippet which ran on every page:

```
if( rand(0, 100) === 50 )
   // increase visitor count
```

What this does is generates a random number, and if it's equal to a fixed number (in this case, 50), it will increment the visitor count. On the page which displays the statistics, the visitor count is multiplied by, for example, 100 before displayed.

I do realize that it might not be ideal to write to the database for each page-view, especially for a very large website like this. But does this really generate correct statistics? Just because 99 visitors's random number is equal to everything but 100 doesn't mean that the next one will get 100.

Am I overreacting, or is this a bad statistic implemention?

Comment: Does the visitor count get increased by 100?

Comment: in the long run, that rand WILL average out to a 1% chance of increasing the visitor count. doesn't explain why it's done this way, but mathematically it's somewhat correct.

Comment: @MarcB It's done to decrease preasure on the database, instead of writing to it 100 times, it will now write ~1 time instead.

Comment: Is this "fixed" different for each page? And if it is, is there any consistency between the fixed numbers in each page? (1,2...49,50,51...)?

Comment: @NadavS. This number is fixed across pages. It's always the same number. Would it make any difference if it weren't?

Comment: @Zar it will not make a difference as I can see. See my answer,through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I've got it. In short - this method **can be** accurate enough & a good method as I understand from **"one of Sweden's most popular websites"**. Let me explain:

There are three factors:

1. **Actual visits** - actual number of page views
2. **Tracked visits** - tracked visits, those that have passed the random number check
3. **Calculated visits** - visits that are shown in the statistics page

And I can translate it into code:

<sub>as seen in any page:</sub>

```
//are you here? you are an ACTUAL visit
if(rand(0, 100) === 50){
    //are you here? you are a TRACKED visit
    //passing info to the database as current number+1
}
```

<sub>and in the statistics page:</sub>

```
//variable $tracked is number of tracked visits from the page

//this is a CALCULATED visit
echo 'Page visits: '.$tracked*100;
```

I can also say that there's a chance of 1% that an actual visit will also become a tracked visit. But now the following question comes: Why the hell do I need to track only 1%  of the visits? Can't I just track all the visits?

> - If every page gets *1000 views/min* this method is a **great
>     performance booster**, and can give rather good results (close enough
>     to the *actual visits*).
> - If every page gets *100 views/min* this method can also boost some
>     performance, and will probably give pretty accurate results.

Talking about performance, imagine 1000 database queries per minute. I personally don't think it's good to do that. So in order to lower the amount of queries, you (or they) actually limit the number of calls to the database by putting a "guard" in the entrance to the database, asking you a random question, just to balance the amount of people inside.

Now of course you'll have to find the perfect balance between performance and accuracy. You can simulate it yourself:

1. `$actual` will help you find the accuracy of the final results
2. `$hits` will show the number of hits (people passed the guard)
3. `$hit_chance` will limit the number of passed results. The higher, the better performance but a lower accuracy. Watch it! If set to 100, the chance will be %1 (1/100), if set to 10000 chance will be 1/10000, if set to 10 1/10 (10%), etc...
4. `$final` will show the calculated visits.

```
$actual = 7000; //set the number of visits you want to check (check the current site statistics!)
$hits = 0; //initialization of variable
$hit_chance = 100; //set hit chance, currently 1%
$answer = intval(round($hit_chance / 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)); //just set answer between 0 and $hit_chance, which is an integer

    for($i=0;$i<$actual;$i++){
        if(rand(0, $hit_chance) === $answer){
            $hits++;
        }
    }

$final = $hits * $hit_chance;
$accuracy = 100 - ((($actual - $final) / $actual) * 100);

echo 'Actual visits: '.$actual;
echo '<br>Hits: '.$hits;
echo '<br>Final results: '.$final;
echo '<br>Result accuracy: '.$accuracy.'%';
```

When thinking again, it depends on you - I think there's no good/bad method. Maybe the servers are so good you don't need it, and maybe they need some performance saving.

Answer (score 0):

The more records they have on it, the more accurate it will be. Once they have over around 1.000.000 hits it's safe to say they have really accurate statistics, because the math will even out on the long run.

On the short term it is pretty terrible in my opinion.

Comment: So only if the website has 1 million or more visitors it'll be accurate? If you don't mind me asking, how did you calculate this number?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry It is a rough number. I have read about 'evening out' somewhere in the book "the mathematics of poker". Of course, that was a poker book but the idea of variance is the same.

Comment: Hmm I have checked out Google but couldn't find the real math for it. If you really like, I could search it up in my book?

Comment: If you have some spare time; sure! Otherwise it's fine, thanks for your answer!